# JavaScript - React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a component and render it once on button click. So if I pressed the button again it would render however does not constantly try and re render itself.

At the moment, I am passing a function to the component and calling at the end of the useEffect. However this seems to not render anything.

Here is what I have in my App.js

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [dataFormat, setDataFormat] = React.useState("");

  const openData = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const closeData = () =>{
    setOpen(false);
  }

  const changeDataFormat = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log(selectedOption);
    setDataFormat(selectedOption);
  };

  return (
    <main className="App">
      <h1>Film Management</h1>
      <SelectDataFormat changeDataFormat={changeDataFormat} />
      <button onClick={openData}>Show Films</button>
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Director</th>
            <th>Stars</th>
            <th>Review</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{open && <FilmTableRows closeData={closeData} dataFormat={dataFormat} />}</tbody>
      </table>
    </main>
  );
}
```

And this is the component I want to render

```
function FilmTableRows(props) {
  const convert = require("xml-js");
  const dataFormat = props.dataFormat;
  const [filmList, setFilmList] = useState([]);
  const baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/FilmRestful/filmapi";

  const getJson = () => {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "data-type": "json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    axios
      .get(baseURL, config)
      .then((res) => {
        const resData = res.data;
        setFilmList(resData);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  const getXML = () => {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "data-type": "xml",
        "Content-type": "application/xml",
        // accept: "application/xml",
      },
    };

    axios
      .get(baseURL, config)
      .then((res) => {
        let newList = [];

        const resData = JSON.parse(
          convert.xml2json(res.data, { compact: true, spaces: 2 })
        );

        resData.films.film.forEach((f) => {
          const film = new Film(
            f.id,
            f.title,
            f.year,
            f.director,
            f.stars,
            f.review
          );
          newList = newList.concat(film);
        });

        setFilmList(newList);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  const getString = () => {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "data-type": "string",
        "Content-type": "application/html",
        // accept: "application/xml",
      },
    };
    axios
      .get(baseURL, config)
      .then((res) => {
        setFilmList(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (dataFormat.value) {
      case "json":
        getJson();
        break;
      case "xml":
        getXML();
        break;
      default:
        getString();
    }
  });

  const child = filmList.map((el, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{el.title}</td>
        <td>{el.year}</td>
        <td>{el.director}</td>
        <td>{el.stars}</td>
        <td>{el.review}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

  return <>{filmList && child}</>;
}
```

Comment: In the `App`, you declare `dataFormat` as string, by using `useState("")`. But in the switch  in `FilmTableRows` you perform `dataFormat.value`...so is it a string, or an object? Make sure you have no error in this part.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix

```
 const [reload, setReload] = useState(false);

 // toggle reload 
 const refresh = () => {
    setReload(r => !r);
 };

  const openData = () => {
       setOpen(true);
       // if you want the same button "Show Films" to refersh
       if (open) {
           refresh();
       }
  };

 return (
  ...
  <button onClick={toggleOpen}>Show Films</button>
  // if you want to use seperate refresh button
  //  <button onClick={refresh}>Refresh</button>
  ...
   <tbody>{open && <FilmTableRows reload={reload} closeData={closeData} dataFormat={dataFormat} />}</tbody>
```

Inside FilmTableRows use reload to trigger fetch

```
 // include depedency to stop fetching on every render
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (dataFormat.value) {
      case "json":
        getJson();
        break;
      case "xml":
        getXML();
        break;
      default:
        getString();
    }
  }, [dataFormat.value, props.reload]);
```

- Ideally you should move the fetch function in the parent,
  so that on refresh fetch data can be called from the event handler
- You can also use a `filter` state instead of `reload` flag and use the filter as a param when making an api call

Hope it helps you towards finding better solution, you can also read the [new React beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity), they will help you to write better code.

Cheers

Comment: dataFormat.value is taken from a select. Therefore it useEffect is called every time there is a change in the select rather than on button click

Comment: Did you mean you wanted to toggle it with the button, or you want to refresh the data in `FilmTableRows` on button click after it is opened, I am trying to understand what is needed to be done

Comment: Refresh the data on button click

Comment: @DKWebservices I edited the answer, hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an Example Code**

```
import * as React from 'react';

function App() {
  //toggle the state (false by default)
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false)

  //Component to be displayed on button click
  const FilmTableRows  = () =>{
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Film</h1>
        <p>FilmTableRows</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      {/* basically switches the value of toggle on every click */}
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>Click Me</button>
      {toggle && <FilmTableRows/>}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

Comment: When toggle is true the user would have to press the button twice to re-render FilmTableRows? Or would this work after the button is pressed once ?

Comment: Works when the button is pressed once